# Print an array after DOM extraction?

Tags: php, arrays, domdocument

I need to print out my array, but **print_r($test)** doesn't work at last...

Here is a simple code :

```
$code = '<html><head></head><body><div class="list"><a href="http://google.com" title="my title"><img src="http://google.com/564308080517287.jpg" alt="my title"></a></div></body></html>'; // Code is simplified here, but imagine you've got much more contents inside
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML( $code );
//
$test = array();
foreach($doc->getElementsByTagName('div') as $div){
    if($div->getAttribute('class') == "list"){
        $ads_count = $div->getElementsByTagName('a')->length;
        for ($i=0; $i<=$ads_count; $i++) {
            $ad = $div->getElementsByTagName('a')->item($i);
            $ad_img = trim($ad->getElementsByTagName('img')->item(0)->getAttribute('src'));
            $test[$i]['img'] = $ad_img;
        }
    }
}
print_r($test); // doesn't work !!
```

Any idea ?

Comment: are you sure that you are getting something in  $test[$i]['img'] = $ad_img;, try to debug your code

Comment: Sure I've got something in $test[$i]['img']. If you place print_r($test); within the "for" loop, the array is printed well.

Comment: It's not an issue with `print_r()`. With this code, you should see an error `Fatal error: Call to a member function getElementsByTagName() on a non-object in /path/to/script.php on line 12`. You probably have error reporting disabled and that's the reason why you're not seeing the error message.

Comment: @AmalMurali : You're right, I've just enabled error reporting. So what should I use instead getElementsByTagName() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  <?php
   $code = '<html><head></head><body><div class="list">
    <a href="http://google.com" title="my title"><img src="http://google.com/564308080517287.jpg" alt="my title"></a></div></body></html>'; // Code is simplified here, but imagine you've got much more contents inside
  $dom = new DOMDocument();
  $dom->loadHtml($code);
  $selector   = new DOMXPath($dom);
  $parceiltable    =   $selector->query("//div[@class='list']/a/img");

  foreach($parceiltable as $key=>$tds){
     $test[]['img']    =   $tds->getAttribute('src');
  }

  print_r($test); 
?>
```